# intraweb XII+isapi+iis7 cookie not saved?

Tags: delphi, cookies, intraweb

I developed an intraweb XII small app which save a cookie:

```
 ck:=THTTPCookie.Create('coo1','valcoo1','',now+7);
 WebApplication.Response.Cookies.Add(ck);
```

Where I reopen the app, I use:

```
WebApplication.Request.CookieFields.Values['coo1']
```

If I run in debug in my pc the app all is OK.
When I deply the isapi dll to an IIS7 server, the cookie is not reloaded.

Could someone help me ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to update to a more recent version, as we had some issues with cookies which had been fixed.